# Why is Lovasz Local Lemma "local" and question about its versions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probabilistic-method

I have some questions about Lovasz's Local Lemma.
There are two versions:

1. (symmetric version):[symmetric Lovasz Local Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma#Symmetric_Lov.C3.A1sz_local_lemma)
2. (Asymmetric version):[asymmetric Lovasz Local Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma#Asymmetric_Lov.C3.A1sz_local_lemma).

My questions are:

1.What is symmetric about the symmeteric version and what is asymmetric about the asymmetric version?

2.Why is the Lemma called "Local"?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

> What is symmetric about the symmetric version and what is asymmetric about the asymmetric version?

In the asymmetric version, there is a function $x\colon\mathcal{A}\to [0,1)$: its value depends on the event $A$ considered, and is not necessarily the same for all events.

In the symmetric version, that $x$ is constant: $x(A)=1/(d+1)$ for every event $A$ considered. That's symmetric (all events are "treated" the same.)

> "such that each event is independent of all the other events except for at most d of them."

You only have *local* dependencies: no event depends globally on every other, only on a few.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Clement C.

Comment: You're welcome!